# Error Validation not showing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code snippet for adding patient in the system but it doesn't show any error messages. I do have `validation_errors()` in the views but still its not showing any
here's the code

```
// Add a new item
public function add()
{
    //some form validation rules here
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i>', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('patient_type_id','Patient Type Id','required|trim|xss_clean|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('middle_name','Middle Name','required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','Gender','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('age','Age','required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[3]|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address','Address','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status','Status','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_number','Contact Number','required|integer|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|xss_clean|email|required');

    //check if the rules are pass
    if($this->form_validation->run()){  
    //if pass save it to the database
        $results = $this->model_nurse_patient->add();
        if($results == TRUE){
            Console::log('data saved into the database');
            $message= "<i class='icon-exclamation-sign'></i>You have successfully added a new patient<br>";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $message);
            redirect(base_url('nurse/patient'));
        }else{
            Console::log('data was not saved');
            $message= "<i class='icon-exclamation-sign'></i>Failed to add a new patient";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $message);
            redirect(base_url('nurse/patient'));
        }

    }else{
        //show the form again with errors
        Console::log('validation not passed');
        $this->create();
    }


}
```

this is the code for $this->create(). it only gets the header ,footer and the view

```
public function create(){
    //just showing the add patient  form
    Console::log($this->model_nurse_patient->get_all_patient_type());
    $create_data['list_rel_status'] = $this->model_nurse_patient->get_all_relationship_status();
    $create_data['list_patient_type'] = $this->model_nurse_patient->get_all_patient_type();
    $this->nurse_patient_header(array('title'=> 'EHR v1'));
    $this->load->view('users/nurse/patient/create',$create_data);
    $this->nurse_patient_footer();
}
```

Comment: Show the `create()` method functionality.

Comment: @HashemQolami i've already updated the code ;)

Comment: Try to remove $this->nurse_patient_footer(); ?